# epub corrupt when successfully downloaded

Tags: php, download, epub, corrupt

I have a code:

```
$name = "jeffrey.epub"; //for naming only
$file = "test/cover/cabang.epub"; //the real file to be downloaded
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

but upon having the download file, it came out corrupted.i also change the `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` to `header('Content-Type: application/epub+zip');` but still it was corrupted, i was wondering what is the problem that the file is being corrupted

Comment: Often, characters are getting added to the output stream that shouldn't be. Disable the Content-Type and check the output.

Comment: its now working i just change `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` to `header('Content-Type: application/epub+zip');` the corruption of data will be prevented, but upon testing on xampp still it will be corrupted but it will just work fine when run on the actual host server/Online